# Expandable custom UITableViewCell for iOS 11+

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I realize that many people have asked this question in various forms and the answers are all over the page, so let me summarize my specific situation in hopes of getting more specific answers. First of all, I'm building for iOS 11+ and have a relatively recent version of XCode (11+). Maybe not the latest, but recent enough.

Basically, I need a self-sizing tableview where the cells may expand and collapse at runtime when the user interacts with them. In `viewDidLoad` I set the rowHeight to `UITableView.automaticDimension` and estimatedRowHeight to some number that's bigger than the canned value of 44. But the cell is not expanding like it should, even though I seem to have tried every bit of advice in the book.

If that matters, I have a custom class for the table cell but no .XIB file for it - the UI is defined directly in the prototype. I've tried a number of other variations, but it feels like the easiest is making a UIStackView the only direct child of the prototype (the "revenue" features so to speak would all be inside it. In my case, they include a label and another tableview - I nest 3 levels deep - but that's probably beside the point) and constraining all 4 of it's edges to the parent. I've tried that, and I've tinkered with the distribution in the stack view (Fill, Fill Evenly, Fill Proportionately), but none of it seems to work. What can I do to make the cells expand properly?

In case anyone's wondering, I used to override `heightForRowAt` but now I don't because it's not easy to predict the height at runtime and I'm hoping the process could be automated.

Comment: Have you tried calling `tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates()` after changing the `isHidden` property of a stack view item? calling these two in a row should tell the table view to recalculate the cell heights.

Comment: *"... a label and another tableview - I nest 3 levels deep ..."* First point: do you have constraints setup properly in your cell so that you are actually expanding/collapsing the cell ***contents***? If not, that's your first task. If your expand/collapse code is *working*, then yes, as aloballi commented, you need to *tell the tableView* that the cell height changed and either call `.beginUpdates(); .endUpdates()` or `tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)`. Best way to do that is with a closure.

Comment: My stack view is never hidden, but I do call ```.beginUpdates()``` and ```.endUpdates()``` at the end of ```viewDidLoad```. Should I move them somewhere else? And I hope my constraints are done right. Each cell (parent, child, grandchild) has exactly one child - a stackview and that stack view is constrained to match the superview. The leading, trailing, top, and bottom are tied of the stack are tied to those of its parent.

Comment: @AppLover - no, those don't go in `viewDidLoad`... Do you have a button or something inside the cell that is supposed to show/hide an arrangedSubview (or multiple views) in your stack view?

Comment: I don't have a button like what you're describing (there's no real need), but I have a number of other buttons on the page. I just tried adding beginUpdates and endUpdates to one of the button's actions and it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Could I be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics...

Here is a vertical `UIStackView` with two labels:

[image]

The red outline shows the frame of the stack view.

If we tap the button, it will set `bottomLabel.isHidden = true`:

[image]

Notice that in addition to being hidden, the stack view *removes* the space it was occupying.

Now, we can do that with a stack view in a table view cell to get expand/collapse functionality.

We'll start with every-other row expanded:

[image]

Now we tap the "Collapse" button for row 1 and we get:

[image]

Not quite what we want. We successfully "collapsed" the cell content, but the table view doesn't know anything about it.

So, we can add a closure... when we tap the button, the code in the cell will show/hide the bottom label ***AND*** it will use the closure to tell the table view what happened. Our `cellForRowAt` func looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! ExpColCell

    c.setData("Top \(indexPath.row)", str2: "Bottom \(indexPath.row)\n2\n3\n4\n5", isCollapsed: isCollapsedArray[indexPath.row])

    c.didChangeHeight = { [weak self] isCollapsed in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        // update our data source
        self.isCollapsedArray[indexPath.row] = isCollapsed
        // tell the tableView to re-run its layout
        self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
    }

    return c
}
```

and we get:

[image]

Here's a complete example:

**Simple "dashed outline view"**

```
class DashedOutlineView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var dashColor: UIColor = .red
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        shapeLayer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [8,8]
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = dashColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```

**The cell class**

```
class ExpColCell: UITableViewCell {

    public var didChangeHeight: ((Bool) -> ())?
    
    private let stack = UIStackView()
    private let topLabel = UILabel()
    private let botLabel = UILabel()
    private let toggleButton = UIButton()
    
    private let outlineView = DashedOutlineView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        // button properties
        toggleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        toggleButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        toggleButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        toggleButton.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
        toggleButton.setTitle("Collapse", for: [])
        
        // label properties
        topLabel.text = "Top Label"
        botLabel.text = "Bottom Label"
        topLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32.0)
        botLabel.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        topLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        botLabel.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        
        botLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        // outline view properties
        outlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // stack view properties
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        // add the labels
        stack.addArrangedSubview(topLabel)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(botLabel)
        
        // add outlineView, stack view and button to contentView
        contentView.addSubview(outlineView)
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        contentView.addSubview(toggleButton)
        
        // we'll use the margin guide
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            
            outlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.topAnchor),
            outlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.leadingAnchor),
            outlineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor),
            outlineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.bottomAnchor),

            toggleButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            toggleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            toggleButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            toggleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 92.0),
            
        ])
        
        // we set the bottomAnchor constraint like this to avoid intermediary auto-layout warnings
        let c = stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        c.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        c.isActive = true

        // set label Hugging and Compression to prevent them from squeezing/stretching
        topLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        topLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        botLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        botLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    func setData(_ str1: String, str2: String, isCollapsed: Bool) -> Void {
        topLabel.text = str1
        botLabel.text = str2
        botLabel.isHidden = isCollapsed
        updateButtonTitle()
    }
    func updateButtonTitle() -> Void {
        let t = botLabel.isHidden ? "Expand" : "Collapse"
        toggleButton.setTitle(t, for: [])
    }
    
    @objc func toggleButtonTapped() -> Void {
        botLabel.isHidden.toggle()
        updateButtonTitle()
        
        // comment / un-comment this line to see the difference
        didChangeHeight?(botLabel.isHidden)
    }
}
```

**and a table view controller to demonstrate**

```
class ExpColTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var isCollapsedArray: [Bool] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(ExpColCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        
        // 16 "rows" start with every-other row collapsed
        for i in 0..<15 {
            isCollapsedArray.append(i % 2 == 0)
        }
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return isCollapsedArray.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! ExpColCell

        c.setData("Top \(indexPath.row)", str2: "Bottom \(indexPath.row)\n2\n3\n4\n5", isCollapsed: isCollapsedArray[indexPath.row])

        c.didChangeHeight = { [weak self] isCollapsed in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            // update our data source
            self.isCollapsedArray[indexPath.row] = isCollapsed
            // tell the tableView to re-run its layout
            self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        }

        return c
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do we set the tableView layout? It looks like I'm missing that step. It feels like the isCollapsedArray should be used somewhere, but it's not shown here. Do you happen to have a link to this GitHub repo so I could look?

Comment: @AppLover - the array is used in `cellForRowAt` and in the `didChangeHeight` closure. I put this (with some changes for clarity) in a GitHub repo here: https://github.com/DonMag/YAECExample

Comment: I really like this approach. How would you animate the change inside the cell? Currently, the table view animates the height switch, but within the cell itself not doing the transition (just one frame, from 0 alpha to 1)

Comment: @RoiMulia - sorry, I don't understand what you're asking... Do you want to know how to animate the `.alpha` property of a UI element?

Comment: Hey @DonMag, I meant, the changes are not animated (they are happening right away), I managed to solve it by wrapping the isHidden inside the animation block with alpha change. The issue tho, in some scenarios the expanding cell animation glitches. Is there a way to make is smooth, always?

Comment: @RoiMulia - using `.isHidden` on stack view arrangedSubviews works great... for many situations. However, as you've seen, it immediately hides/shows the subview which may not be the desired visual effect. I updated my GitHub repo (https://github.com/DonMag/YAECExample) with an "Example 2" that uses a different approach to allow for the fade-in/-out effect. You may want to take a look.

Comment: Hey @DonMag, It's looks better now, but the glitch is not there. Here is a video showing the issue. Please look at the bottom of the collection view, it's pushing the new cells but it's glitchy: https://ufile.io/zjxsz1p6

Comment: @RoiMulia - do you mean the bottom few rows "disappear" before the animation occurs? If so, that is an inherent visual effect when cell heights change... the table view calculates how many cells need to be shown and only renders those cells. If you're expanding a cell, then fewer cells will fit. This happens on a simple `.reloadRows(at: ...)` call as well. The only way I've found to get around that is to use a normal view controller with a tableview as a subview, make the tableview much taller than the view, and set the `.contentInset.bottom` to offset the difference.

Comment: Hmm Okay got it. Would you like to explore this issue via paid consultant? We are trying to develop a very accurate component, we need it to be as smooth as smooth can be. Is that something you can consider? @DonMag

Comment: @RoiMulia - sure... but first, I updated my GitHub repo again... take a look and see if Example 3 looks usable.

Comment: That's awesome! @DonMag, It's looking very good. Should there be a problem to make an "only one cell is expended at a time"? So in theory, initial state: no cell expanded, then expanding a cell than choosing a different cell, the first is getting closed while the second is expanding. Should we expect an issue with the example 3 approach?

Comment: @RoiMulia - you'll run into a couple issues, mainly dealing with vertical positioning. For example, if a tall row is expanded, but scrolled up so it is mostly out-of-view, when expanding the row below it the "tall row" will collapse, pulling the rows below it up and off the screen. Give it a shot...