# How to set constraints dynamically whether an element is present or not?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to make a constraint that adapts whether an item is present or not in a design, sometimes it is, sometimes not but the bottom of my container is always the same. How would you do to make it resize depending of the presence of this item ?

Here is a screenshot below for better understanding :

[image]

As you can see sometimes there is pictures with "voir x réponses" at the bottom, sometimes not. But still the spacing is always the same.

The bottom lines are stackviews with alignment and distribution set to fill.

The question is : how to make the bottom of the container reduce when the last line is not present ?

Comment: You need to show how you have your constraints setup. *"... bottom lines are stackviews ..."* Do you mean the images and a label with "voir x réponses" are in a horizontal stack view? If so, is that stack view in a vertical stack view along with the other elements? And... is this a tableViewCell (or collectionViewCell)?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Yes there are in horizontal stack views plus it is a tableView. The constraints are set to 0 for top leading trailing and bottom for each stack view.

Comment: If your horizontal stack view (the images and a label with "voir x réponses") is the last arranged subview of a vertical stack view, you should be able to set it to `.isHidden = true` to remove it **and** the space it occupies. See this answer I just wrote up for a similar question:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537820/6257435

Comment: I don't even know how I managed to not think about that. Thank you very much for your time man !